# how to speed data reading in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have 400,000 data in my Mongo DB collection.Every Document have count(number).I want read these documents and add all numbers to get total.I get Mongo DB Collection data using Node.js and mongoose then calculate total using for-loop.it take around two minute.i want to take it in one second.is there any way to speed this process?.I found mapreduce can speedup this.what is the most efficient way to speedup this process.

i take Mongodb model like this

```
exports.getDownloads = function(processPD,processDW,responseMDW) {
     DailyDowloadsModel.find({},function(err,foundData){
        var select;
        if (err) {
            log.error(clientIP +" - DB Connection downloads failed - error");
            res.status(500).send();
        }
        else {
            if(foundData.length == 0){
                var responseObject = null;
                if(select && select == 'count'){
                    responseObject = {count: 0};
                }
            }else {
                var responseObject = foundData;
                if (select && select == "count") {
                    responseObject = {count: foundData.length};
                }
                processPD(processDW,responseObject,responseMDW);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

sample Document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5719ef37264f87331a3d0c54"),
    "refunds" : "0",
    "downloads" : "6",
    "country" : "CA",
    "date" : "2013-09-06",
    "product_id" : "20600001319328",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I want to calculate total downloads.

Comment: How large your average document is? Please post a sample document.

Comment: I add a sample document

Comment: Good. where is count(number)? as you mentioned in your statement above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options to calculate total.

**OPTION 1:** *aggregation framework*

Performing such actions using aggregation framework will be much faster as compared to sending all documents to client and doing math over there.

**Note:** your `downloads` field is string, it should be a number.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
 {$group:{_id:null, total:{$sum:"$downloads"}}}
])
```

On my Machine (Macbook Pro), it's returning total in under half a second. I'm running test on 400000 documents.

**OPTION 2:** *map reduce*
Though it is highly recommended to update your document structure to accept `downloads` as number. However, if this is not an option for whatever reason, your best bet is map reduce functionality offered by MongoDB.

```
var map = function(){
    emit(1, parseInt(this.downloads));
};

var reduce = function(key, values){
    var reducedValue = Array.sum(values);
    return reducedValue;
};

db.collection.mapReduce(map, reduce, {
  out: { "inline" : 1}
});
```

map reduce is slower than aggregation framework as you can see but much faster than your original approach. It emit output as:

```
{ 
    "results" : [
        {
            "_id" : NumberInt(1), 
            "value" : NumberInt(2400000)
        }
    ], 
    "timeMillis" : NumberInt(4112), 
    "counts" : {
        "input" : NumberInt(400000), 
        "emit" : NumberInt(400000), 
        "reduce" : NumberInt(4000), 
        "output" : NumberInt(1)
    }, 
    "ok" : NumberInt(1)
}
```

As you can notice, it took roughly 4 seconds to complete operation.

Answer (score 0):

Use Mongo DB aggregation

```
db.DailyDowloadsModel.aggregate([{$group:{_id:null, totalDownloads:{$sum:"$downloads"}}}]);
```

But before that INDEX the download field with this command in Mongo DB.

```
db.DailyDowloadsModel.createIndex( { downloads: 1 });
```